# Async / await outer variable access

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer

```
const puppeteerOTPTrigger = async ({ username, password }) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("example.com");
  await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click("div")]);
 
  await page.$eval("#Login_userName", (el) => {
    return (el.value = username); // in this line i am getting the error 
                                     ReferenceError: username is not defined
  });
  await page.$eval("#Login_password", (el) => (el.value = "password")); static value woking 
 
};
```

In the example above I am unable to access the "username" variable inside the await callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `async/await`.  This is because puppeteer is running your callback in the page context, not in your program's context.

You should pass the username argument as another argument to `.$eval()`.  Then, you will be able to access it that way as an argument to your callback.

```
await page.$eval("#Login_userName", (el, name) => {
  return (el.value = name); // use the argument you passed
}, username);
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is working but can you please tell me how is it working!!

Comment: @NikhilTayal - You're passing `username` as an argument to `page.$eval()` (see it passed after the callback).   `$.eval()` then passes that argument on to your callback where you can then access it from within the context of your callback in the context of the page.

Comment: @NikhilTayal - If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible because the `username` is available in Nodejs runtime and `el.value = username` is being executed in browser(where username is not available).